Entity Framework Core : Select() - turn an IList<> property into a joined string?
I have the following select which returns the 4 columns I want:
var allUsers = await dbContext.AppUsers
    .Where(u => allUserIds.Contains(u.IdentityUsersId))
    .Include(u => u.Following)
    .Select(u => new
    {
        u.Name,
        u.Email,
        u.Phone!.FormattedNumber,
        u.Following
    })
    .ToListAsync();

However Following is a List<Organization>. What I want is the Organization.Name. Is there a way to have it, in the select, return a List<string>?
And if so, is there a way to instead of it being a List<string>, it can be a string that is a string.Join() of all the names?
Update: I added C# as a tag because now that I see the answer, this is a dynamic objects as used by Entity Frameworks question. And I think this is a useful Q&A to show how dynamic objects can be used in an EF select.

I guess you posted the wrong code ?

@jeb correct code - the above runs. But the AppUser.Following is a List, TIA

Ah i got it. Try Following = u.Following.Select(f => f.Name).ToList()

And the Join: string.Join(", ", u.Following.Select(f => f.Name))

@jeb first off thank you. If you write all that up as an answer, happy to accept it. Second, this is powerful, especially on the part of EF. Really cool. thanks

Glad i could help. Linq is pretty complicated. With ef core even more. I takes some time get familiar to it

To return a List<string> of organization names you can Select the Name property and make a list:
    .Select(u => new
    {
        u.Name,
        u.Email,
        u.Phone!.FormattedNumber,
        Following = u.Following.Select(f => f.Name).ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();

To return a single string that concatenates all organization names you can use string.Join inside of the anonymous type:
    .Select(u => new
    {
        u.Name,
        u.Email,
        u.Phone!.FormattedNumber,
        Following = string.Join(", ", u.Following.Select(f => f.Name))
    })
    .ToListAsync();

